# Создание запроса в 1с

Tags: 1с

Как создавать правильно запросы? в интернете много информации, но всё как-то непонятно. вот задание. нужно из справочника сделать отбор по конкретным данным из двух полей. прикрепляю пример,что сделал сам через конструктор,а потом сам пытался дописать,но он не рабочий.

```
Запрос = Новый Запрос;
Запрос.Текст = "
    |ВЫБРАТЬ
    |   РеквизитыОпераций.Код КАК Код,
    |   РеквизитыОпераций.Наименование КАК Наименование
    |ИЗ
    |   Справочник.РеквизитыОпераций КАК РеквизитыОпераций
    |ГДЕ Код=&11 и Наимование =&СчетУчетаНДС";
Результат = Запрос.Выполнить();
```

Comment: ну вот отбор по коду я нашёл,надо было проще
`|ГДЕ
 |Код = 11`
но как найти по наименованию?

Comment: Получилось сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Параметр не должен называться 11, 
|ГДЕ Код=&11 и Наимование =&СчетУчетаНДС";
// Правильно так:
|ГДЕ Код=&Код и Наимование =&СчетУчетаНДС";

// Перед выполнением нужно установить параметры
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Код", ЗначениеКод);
Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("СчетУчетаНДС", СокрЛП(СчетУчетаНДС)); // Следим чтобы совпадали типы !

Результат = Запрос.Выполнить();
Выборка = Результат.Выбрать();
Пока Выборка.Следующий() Цикл
  // Делаем все что нужно
  Сообщить("Код = " + СокрЛП(Выборка.Код));
КонецЦикла;
```

Comment: Всё равно не понимаю, вот по коду понятно,вроде....но оно почему-то всё равно не работает. мне просто надо переменной присвоить конкретное значение из справочника, ну т.е. выбрать именно тот счётНДС у которого код =11,а оно и так не фурычит

Comment: В конфигураторе открой Справочник по которому запрос, найди реквизит Код - посмотри какой у него тип (Строка/Число) при установке параметра нужно передавать значение аналогичного типа ! И наконец проверь а есть ли в справочнике элемент удовлетворяющий ВСЕМ условиям ГДЕ ...